# What is the differences between swap space and cpu cache?

Tags: memory-management, cpu, cpu-architecture

When I googled about TLB vs CPU cache, I found this graph.
[image]

According to the virtual memory mechanism, if we cannot find things in physical memory or disk cache, CPU will look for things in the disk(swap place). That's to say, if we extend this picture, a disk cache should be drawn inside main memory and a disk should be drawn after the main memory. Do I understand them correctly?

Reference: [whats-difference-between-cpu-cache-and-tlb](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-cpu-cache-and-tlb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*everything* about CPU cache is different / opposite from swap space.  Hardware managed vs. SW managed, on die vs. even "farther" away than DRAM.

If you consider an old way of doing virtual memory (back in the days when it was recommended to have swap space = 2x DRAM), and you have an OS that truly allocates swap space as backing for all virtual memory allocations:

I guess you could sort of look at main memory as a backing store for CPU cache, similar to how swap space is the backing store for anonymous memory pages.  (i.e. that isn't memory-mapped to a file on disk.)

The manual software-managed and software-visible nature of page faults does mean there are major differences, though.

One of the most important is that **CPU cache (normally) caches based on *physical* address**, while swap space is purely about virtual address space.  You can never have swap space in physical address space (except with memory mapped non-volatile storage like an NV-DIMM...)

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your kind reply. This is the place I get confused. You see, in the graph, the virtual address has already be converted to physical address after TLB/MMU. But swap space is located in disk, which is after page fault in main memory. How the CPU continue to use virtual address to find things in the disk?

Comment: @MichaelPeng: The CPU *doesn't* find things on disk.  Swap space is 100% software managed.  The CPU just generates a page fault when it can't find a translation to physical in the page tables, or the mapping doesn't have write permission for a write, or exec for code-fetch, etc.  It's up to software to figure out whether that page is actually valid and a page needs to be paged in from disk (hard page fault) or copy-on-write copied (one example of soft page fault), or really wants mapped (deliver SIGSEGV signal: segfault)

Comment: So you mean the page fault actually happens before the TLB/MMU? That makes sense for CPU to use the vitual address in this procedure. And you mentioned that CPU doesn't find things on disk, if so, whose duty to swap correct things out of the disk and place them to RAM? And then CPU read data in RAM again?

Comment: @MichaelPeng: No, it happens after TLB lookup fails and the resulting page-walk still doesn't find an entry.  The MMU isn't really a separate piece of hardware these days (it's all integrated into the core), but it's "the MMU" that raises a page-fault exception if there is one.  And like I said in my answer and comment, software manages swapping.  Specifically the kernel, obviously, in the page-fault handler for triggering page-in, or in the page allocator for evicting pages.  Once the page is present in RAM and wired into the page tables, the kernel can restart a process that page faulted.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.You are soooo familiar with these.

Comment: @MichaelPeng: Yes, I am, but most of that is super-basics of operating-systems and virtual memory, also the basics of understanding performance costs of TLB miss vs. hard/soft page fault.  If you want to know more about TLBs and page walks and low-level details of caches, see [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32256250), and [How does CPU make data request via TLBs and caches?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22572316), and also [VIPT Cache: Connection between TLB & Cache?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46480015)

Comment: Nice to know that. Thanks coach.